# .Net Core MVC 3.1 - How to change css (or scss) global variable, dynamically based on Session Values?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, .net-core, sass, asp.net-core-mvc

**How can I dynamically change global variable in css (or scss)  in .net core mvc 3.1 based on session values which are also dynamically reloaded and changed if necessary when going between different pages?**
This is what I have done so far. But please also suggest other methods like if I have to use different technologies like LESS or just plan css or anything else for that matter. Would be nice, if i can edit css global variables from the controller. Thanks in Advance :)

- **site.scss**

  /* Global Variables */ 
  **$tabButton**: '*Copperplate Gothic','Georgia*';

  /* Tab Buttons Styling */ 
  **#tabButton** { 
  border-radius: *15px*; 
  font-family: *$tabButton*; 
  }

Comment: first, do you have runtime transpiling to css in production (or intend to)?

Comment: @BrettCaswell - Don't have it but wouldn't mind if necessary and if it solves the problem. Could you please let me know about how I can do that ?

Comment: You could try to pre-add multiple CSS style with a different class name, then based on the session value to set the different class name. Besides, you could also try to use [JQuery css()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) method to change the related style properties.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, multiple css was not applicable since there was no way to know what the new styles would be. I have posted the solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix this problem. I created a new themecontroller and set the stylings in them using session values on a action that returns partial view.

```
public class ThemeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult ThemeManager()
    {
        
        ThemeModel themeModel = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<ThemeModel>("ThemeSettings");

        if(themeModel == null)
        {
            themeModel = new ThemeModel();
        }
        themeModel.primaryColor = "red";


        //var colors = await _apiService.GetThemeColors();
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";                        
        return PartialView(themeModel);
    }
}
```

I then put this into my layout file like below,

```
<link href="@Url.Action("ThemeManager", "Theme")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now in the partial View,

```
@model ThemeModel
@{
    var color = Model.primaryColor;
}
<style>
   @if (color == "red")
    {
        @:.image{ box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;-khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;}
    }
    else
    {
        @:.image{}
    }
</style>
```